# Extending Cauchy-Schwarz to any $p \in (1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality, roots, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $n$ non-negative real number $\left\lbrace a_i\right\rbrace_{i=1}^n$, we know that using Cauchy-Schwarz, one can prove that
$$ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt{a_i} \leq \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i} 
$$

Is it true that the same would apply to any $p \in (1,\infty)$, i.e.
$$ 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt[p]{a_i} \leq \sqrt[p]{n} \cdot \sqrt[p]{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i} \ ?
$$

If not, can we multiply the right term by some constant depending on $p$ which will result in having the same form of the inequality?

Please advise.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure

Comment: @ClementC. I might be missing something, but isn't he applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $\sqrt{a_i} \cdot 1$, resulting in $\sqrt{a_i}^2 = a_i$?

Comment: @Klaus My bad, early morning... you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure.

Comment: I am familiar with Hölder's inequality, yet how is this connected to here?
I need a bound on the sum of $p$-roots using the $p$-root of the sum.

Comment: Just do the same thing as you did with Cauchy-Schwarz. In fact, Cauchy-Schwarz is a special case of Hölder.

Answer (score 2):

By Holder's inequality, for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, $1\le p,q$, $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt[p]{a_i}\le\|1\|_q\|(\sqrt[p]{a_i})\|_p=\sqrt[q]{n}\sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}$$ Note that the root power of $n$ is not $p$ (except when $p=2$).

Comment: I just proved it using Klaus's suggestion, yet i thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong.

Try $n=p=3$ and $a_1=a_2=a_3=1.$

We need to prove that $$3\leq\sqrt[3]3\cdot\sqrt[3]3,$$ which is impossible.

By the way, by Holder
$$n^{p-1}\sum_{k=1}^na_k\geq\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_k\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\right)^p,$$ which gives $$n^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\left(a_k\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
.$$